# Problema al imprimir datos de un constructor POO php

Tags: php, poo

Estoy estudiando POO en php, y he hecho este codigo, pero al momento de ejecutarlo, la pagina se me queda en blanco y no me muestra los datos que he ingresado anteriormente, ¡Alguna ayuda?

```
<?php 

class coche{
    var $ruedas;
    var $color;
    var $motor;
}
function __construct(){
    $this->ruedas=4;
    $this->color="";
    $this->motor=1600;
}
function arrancar(){
    echo "Estoy arrancando";
}
function frenar (){
    echo "Estoy frenando";
}
function girar(){
    echo "Estoy girando";
}

$renault=new coche();
$chevrolet= new coche();
$mazda = new coche();

$mazda->girar();
echo $mazda->ruedas;
 ?>
```

y me sale este error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method coche::girar() in
>   C:\wamp\www\Curso Php\Video 14. (Programacion Orientada a
>   Objetos)\POO(III) (Llamadas a metodos con parametros y reutilizacion
>   de codigo)\poo3.php on line 36

La linea 36 vendria siendo  $mazda->girar(); no veo el error

Comment: Estas declarando las funciones **fuera** de la clase. Tienes que declararlas **dentro**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero que nada estas usando la palabra reservada `var`, **no esta mal, pero es de la versión PHP 4**. Los métodos los estas declarando afuera. Tu clase yo la escribiría así:

```
class coche
{
    public $ruedas;
    public $color;
    public $motor;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->ruedas=4;
        $this->color="";
        $this->motor=1600;
    }
    function arrancar()
    {
        echo "Estoy arrancando";
    }
    function frenar()
    {
        echo "Estoy frenando";
    }
    function girar()
    {
        echo "Estoy girando";
    }
}
```

Aunque siempre es aconsejable usar variables privadas y acceder a estas por un método, como una cuestión de buenas prácticas.

Comment: Imprime correctamente. Lo probe y todo.

Comment: Los de 'var' si funciona, por que se mantiene por temas de compatibilidad, lo se por que lo probe y estoy usando PHP 7

Comment: Invocando a phpinfo(), tengo la version 7.1.8, y aun así a mi el 'var' me lo toma sin problemas.

Comment: Lo de las propiedades publicas, no es aconsejable, por cuestiones de buenas practicas, pero poder se puede hacer, cada quien programa como quiere.

Comment: Solo como nota: La forma de declaración de una variable de PHP 4 con la palabra clave **var** todavía es soportado (como un **sinónimo de public**) por razones de compatibilidad. En PHP 5 antes de 5.1.3, su uso genera un Warning E_STRICT.